# Why doesn't this INSERT command work?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

My system does not come with any errors, but there is not added anything to tblHardware when I try to add.
This is my code.

```
private void btnTilfoj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    conn.Open();
    commandstring = "INSERT INTO tblItUdstyr([HardwareType], [KobsDato], [SerieNr]) VALUES(@HardwareType, @KobsDato, @SerieNr)";
    comm = new SqlCommand(commandstring, conn);

    comm.Parameters.Add("@HardwareType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    comm.Parameters["@HardwareType"].Value = cbHardware.Text.ToString();

    comm.Parameters.Add("@KobsDato", SqlDbType.Date);
    comm.Parameters["@KobsDato"].Value = dtpKobsDato.Value;

    comm.Parameters.Add("@SerieNr", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    comm.Parameters["@SerieNr"].Value = txtSerienr.Text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` call

Comment: You never execute the command (or close the connection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every command should be executed in some way.
Your code is fine, but lacks of the last call

Use something like this

```
 commandstring = "INSERT INTO tblItUdstyr([HardwareType], [KobsDato], [SerieNr]) " + 
                 "VALUES(@HardwareType, @KobsDato, @SerieNr)";
using(conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using(comm = new SqlCommand(commandstring, conn))
{
     conn.Open();
     comm.Parameters.Add("@HardwareType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     comm.Parameters["@HardwareType"].Value = cbHardware.Text.ToString();
     comm.Parameters.Add("@KobsDato", SqlDbType.Date);
     comm.Parameters["@KobsDato"].Value = dtpKobsDato.Value;
     comm.Parameters.Add("@SerieNr", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     comm.Parameters["@SerieNr"].Value = txtSerienr.Text.ToString();
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();  //This is the call that sends your data to the database
}
```

Notice how I have put all your code inside a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). This will enforce the closing and disposing of the SqlCommand and SqlConnection after you have finished. Also in case of exceptions

Answer (score 2):

You need to run this:

```
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, there are some other things I'd recommend doing:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    conn.Open();

    commandstring = "INSERT INTO tblItUdstyr([HardwareType], [KobsDato], [SerieNr]) VALUES(@HardwareType, @KobsDato, @SerieNr)";
    comm = new SqlCommand(commandstring, conn);

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HardwareType", cbHardware.Text.ToString());
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KobsDato", dtpKobsDato.Value);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerieNr", txtSerienr.Text.ToString());

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I added the `using` because that will properly close and dispose the `SqlConnection`. Further, I added the `AddWithValue` method because it's streamlined and more accurate as far as type matching.